# ps server still running heavily after all worker has completed

Tags: tensorflow, cluster-computing, ps

I use tensorflow cluster to speedup training, I don't know why
ps server still running heavily after all worker has completed?

Answer (score 0):

A parameter server in distributed TensorFlow never terminates. See discussion in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4713#issuecomment-254087067) issue on GitHub.